# What are the required Jars to run Hibernate 5 on Tomcat?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, tomcat

I already added the following files for Hibernate available in the download for Hibernate ? Is there any jar that I am missing ? I am using SQL Server 2014 as the database.

I have already added the following in the Web Application:

```
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-5.0.7.Final.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1-sources.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
    /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/sqljdbc4-3.0.jar
```

Comment: looks good, except for the "jstl-api..-sources.jar", as this should contain source files, not binary compiled class files.

Comment: @MWiesner Which one is that one ?

Comment: Should I remove that ?

Comment: You can do that, as it is "not useful"... it looks weird to me.

Comment: Still no luck. Throwing up weird class not found exceptions

Comment: Edit the original post and add that Exception stack trace (!), otherwise nobody will know what we are talking about here?

Comment: It fixed that. Awesome.

Comment: you're last comment does not help anybody except you, as you don't explain what was going wrong and HOW you solved this...

Comment: Yes, I am going to put the final configuration as an Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issues by adding these jars and it fixed the problem.

```
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core-5.0.7.Final.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1-sources.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/sqljdbc4-3.0.jar
/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar
```

Hope this helps future readers.

Comment: this answer is misleading... You just added `hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar` which is in fact the EntityManager part of Hibernate. The rest of the other Jar files was already contained in your setup. Please be specific on the difference.